# Triangle Inequality Theorem in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

hi guys I'm kind of new to programing I'm learning on my own sorry if i made any mistakes that is obvious for you. 
 I'm trying to make a program with batch where you can put in 3 numbers and the program will tell you weather you can make a triangle with those ratios ( like 1cm 2cm and 3cm ) and I'm having problems with the usage of <,> 
(2>1 two is greater than 1) how can i use greater than in batch?
and i would appreciate if someone could explain the solution in a way that i can understand it with little knowledge of programing .
Thanks for the help!

```
@echo off
mode 1000

color a0

goto block1

:block1

set /p input1=
set /p input2=
set /p input3=

pause
if %input1% + %input2% << %input3% goto invalid
if %input1% + %input3% << %input2% goto invalid
if %input2% + %input3% << %input1% goto invalid
if %input1% + %input2% == %input3% goto invalid
if %input1% + %input3% == %input2% goto invalid
if %input2% + %input3% == %input1% goto invalid
goto valid


:valid
echo this triangle is valid
pause
goto block1


:invalid
echo this triangle is invalid
pause
goto block1
```

Comment: You can only do math with `SET /A`.  Read the help for the `SET` and `IF` commands.  They are quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Check [`IF`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) command syntax. You can't perform arithemtic operations in if checks , so you need an additional variables (check also [`set /a`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)). Also you can use less or equal (`LEQ`) to reduce your code :

```
@echo off
mode 1000

color a0

goto block1

:block1

set /p input1=
set /p input2=
set /p input3=

set /a sum1=input2+input3
set /a sum2=input1+input3
set /a sum3=input1+input2
pause
if %sum3% LEQ %input3% goto invalid
if %sum2% LEQ %input2% goto invalid
if %sum1% LEQ %input1% goto invalid

goto valid


:valid
echo this triangle is valid
pause
goto block1


:invalid
echo this triangle is invalid
pause
goto block1
```

Comment: Is that a type on sum3?